# Is there a way to implement Resource file translation on my custom CMS system?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I currently have a piece of Razor script, which talks to a ViewModel containing questions and Answers pertaining to an FAQ page.

I'm aiming for this to be content-manageable through the use of a for loop as per my below code.

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
            @if (questions.Length == answers.Length)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < questions.Length; i++)
                {

                    var html = string.Format(@"
            <div class='panel-group' id='accordion{1}'>
               <div class='panel panel-default'>
                 <div class='panel-heading' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion{1}' data-target='#collapse{1}'>
                   <h4 class='panel-title'>
                    <a class='accordion-toggle collapsed'>{0}</a>
                   </h4>
                 </div>
                   <div id='collapse{1}' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                <div class='panel-body'>
                  {2}
                </div>
                  </div>
        </div>", questions[i], IDGenerator, answers[i]);

                    @Html.Raw(html)

                    IDGenerator.Append("1");


                }
            }

            @{
                IDGenerator.Clear();
            }
```

This is working rather well at the moment; I am able to update Questions/answers on my DB and populate that on my view dynamically, absolutely fine.

The problem is, I need to be able to translate them through the use of Resource files, I can do this fine with static values (labels, buttons etc) but I have absolutely no idea how to do this with the use of a loop and dynamic values.

Is this possible to do at all?

Comment: If questions and answers are in the database, then you should put translations in the database too.

Comment: But would that not make my .resx files redundant?

Comment: Don't use .resx file for dynamic content translation